# remove screenshot.png via dashboard

Tags: customization, themes, admin, dashboard

How can you remove screenshot.png, or change it if removal is not an option, via the WP dashboard? I know you can do it with FTP. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where `screenshot.png` is? Are you referring to files in plugins? Something that was uploaded? It's not clear

Comment: Is it about the theme's preview image or screenshot added for plugin?

Comment: Theme's preview image